# Simple maintenance page

Tags: acumatica

I have a small table which only allows me to enter one row.  Any time I try to add another row, I get an error stating another process changed the data.  I have done so many other customizations much more involved, but I just cannot figure this one out.  Any ideas out there folks?

Much appreciated!

This is the DAC:

```
namespace EDIASNs
{
    using System;
    using PX.Data;
    using PX.Objects.GL;

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class EDCompanyData : PX.Data.IBqlTable
    {
        #region BranchID
        public abstract class branchID : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected int? _BranchID;
        [Branch()]
        public virtual int? BranchID { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region Active
        public abstract class active : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected bool? _Active;
        [PXDBBool()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Active")]
        [PXDefault(true)]
        public virtual bool? Active { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region Url
        public abstract class url : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected string _Url;
        [PXDBString(100, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Url")]
        public virtual string Url { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region Service
        public abstract class service : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected string _Service;
        [PXDBString(100, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Service Name")]
        public virtual string Service { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region EDIAccount
        public abstract class eDIAccount : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected string _EDIAccount;
        [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Account")]
        public virtual string EDIAccount { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region EDILoginName
        public abstract class eDILoginName : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected string _EDILoginName;
        [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Login Name")]
        public virtual string EDILoginName { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region EDIPassword
        public abstract class eDIPassword : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected string _EDIPassword;
        [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Password")]
        public virtual string EDIPassword { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region EDIApiKey
        public abstract class eDIApiKey : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected string _EDIApiKey;
        [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Api Key")]
        public virtual string EDIApiKey { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region AutoReleaseInvoices
        public abstract class autoReleaseInvoices : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected bool? _AutoReleaseInvoices;
        [PXDBBool()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Auto Release Invoices")]
        [PXDefault(true, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        public virtual bool? AutoReleaseInvoices { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region NoteID
        public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected Guid? _NoteID;
        [PXDBField()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "NoteID")]
        public virtual Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region ProjectID
        public abstract class projectID : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected int? _ProjectID;
        [PXDBInt()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ProjectID")]
        public virtual int? ProjectID { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region CreatedByID
        public abstract class createdByID : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected Guid? _CreatedByID;
        [PXDBCreatedByID()]
        public virtual Guid? CreatedByID { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region CreatedByScreenID
        public abstract class createdByScreenID : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected string _CreatedByScreenID;
        [PXDBCreatedByScreenID()]
        public virtual string CreatedByScreenID { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region CreatedDateTime
        public abstract class createdDateTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected DateTime? _CreatedDateTime;
        [PXDBCreatedDateTime()]
        public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region LastModifiedByID
        public abstract class lastModifiedByID : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected Guid? _LastModifiedByID;
        [PXDBLastModifiedByID()]
        public virtual Guid? LastModifiedByID { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region LastModifiedByScreenID
        public abstract class lastModifiedByScreenID : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected string _LastModifiedByScreenID;
        [PXDBLastModifiedByScreenID()]
        public virtual string LastModifiedByScreenID { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region LastModifiedDateTime
        public abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected DateTime? _LastModifiedDateTime;

        [PXDBLastModifiedDateTime()]
        public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region tstamp
        public abstract class Tstamp : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected byte[] _tstamp;
        [PXDBTimestamp()]
        public virtual byte[] tstamp { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is the graph:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.SM;
using PX.Data;


namespace EDIASNs
{
    public class EDCompanyMaint : PXGraph<EDCompanyMaint, EDCompanyData>
    {
        public PXSelect<EDCompanyData> EDCompany;
    }
}
```

This is the SQL Server table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EDCompanyData](
    [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BranchID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Service] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [Url] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [EDIAccount] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [EDILoginName] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [EDIPassword] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [EDIApiKey] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [AutoReleaseInvoices] [bit] NULL,
    [NoteID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ProjectID] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedByID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedByScreenID] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedByID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedByScreenID] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [tstamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [EDCompanyData_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CompanyID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the error you get is caused by the primary key constraint violation on the database level. Because you inherited from the PXGraph class with 2 generic type parameters, which has a bunch of actions pre-defined, PXDataSource always tries to insert a new row into EDCompanyData, instead of updating the only existing record in the database. I would suggest to inherit from PXGraph class with only 1 generic type parameter and define only Save and Cancel actions:

```
public class EDCompanyMaint : PXGraph<EDCompanyMaint, EDCompanyData>
{
    public PXSave<EDCompanyData> Save;
    public PXCancel<EDCompanyData> Cancel;

    public PXSelect<EDCompanyData> EDCompany;
}
```

Comment: I'm so embarrassed.  I didn't realize the primary key was only company id so obviously I can only have one record.  I will change the PK to include the service name.  Thanks.